# how to compare response.Text with Some String in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem, I'm returning data from a servlet to an AJAX function and in this function I want to compare the `response.Text` with some String, e.g x, but it does not compare it. I have the following code;

```
function ajaxhandler()
{
    tableHtml=response.Text
    if(tableHtml=='true')
        alert("Valid Move");
    else
        alert("invalid move")
}
```

but this doesnt alert anything.

in my servlet i had done this;

```
void myfunction(HttpServlet request,HttpServlet response)
{
String user=(session.getAttribute("user"));
if(user=="john")
out.println("true");
else
out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: Care to share with us what `response.Text` is? (what it equals to)

Comment: If you are using XMLHttpRequest, and for example your XMLHttpRequest object is called `xhr`, the proper way to reference the response text is `xhr.responseText`

Comment: actually m getting the data in responseText but the data m getting is not compared in javascript as i have mentioned in the example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the result of `console.log(JSON.Stringify(response));`. I believe you are not sending a correct JSON response. Try this instead:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
if(user.equals("john"))
    jsonObject.put ("Text", "true");
else
    jsonObject.put ("Text", "false");
out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: anyother method than JSON m not using JSON i have a very simple project of jsp and ajax but i got stuck here..........

Comment: i think i have mentioned it above, it is coming from out.println("true")

Comment: @john there's a difference between "**if** it's comming" and "**how** it's comming". **I'm asking what does the text look like.**

Comment: i still dont get what you are saying "What doest the text look like" terribly sorry

Comment: @john you have an object named `response` in your js. You believe this object has a property `Text` with a value `true` or a value `false`. Make sure that is correct: `JSON.stringify(response)` will tell you. Want it or not, **every object in js is a JSON object by definition**. JSON means javascript object notation.

Comment: @john - If you use Firefox, install an extension called Firebug on it. Where you set tableHtml, put a break right after that. See what the value is in tableHtml and post that as an update.